# Concurrently apply function to each element in a tuple in Erlang

Tags: concurrency, erlang, tuples

I have a tuple `{apple, pear, orange, banana}`

I also have a function `make_juice/1`:

```
 make_juice(apple) ->
    apple_juice();
 make_juice(pear) ->
    pear_juice();
 make_juice(orange) ->
    orange_juice();
 make_juice(banana) ->
    banana_juice().
```

I want to apply this function to each element in the tuple, so I get the result

`{apple_juice, pear_juice, orange_juice, banana_juice}`

Because all the functions`apple_juice/0`, `pear_juice/0`, `orange_juice/0`, `banana_juice/0` could fail unexpectedly. I want to apply I don't want it to interrupt my result.

I want to apply the function to the elements concurrently. In any case of failure I would still get part of the result back:

`{apple_juice, fail, orange_juice, fail}`

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this code, which executes the map in parallel and at the same time if there is an exception replace the result with fail

```
-module(juice).
-compile(export_all).

make_juice(apple) ->
    apple_juice;
make_juice(pear) ->
    pear_juice;
make_juice(orange) ->
    orange_juice;
make_juice(banana) ->
    0/0.

pmap(Function, List) ->    
    S = self(),
    Pids = lists:map(fun(El) ->
                 spawn(fun() ->
                       execute(S, Function, El) end) 
             end, 
             List),
    gather(Pids).

execute(Recv, Function, Element) ->
    Recv ! {self(), Function(Element)}.

gather([]) ->
    [];
gather([H|T]) ->
    receive
    {H, Ret} ->
        [Ret|gather(T)]
    end.



test() ->
    Elements = [apple, banana, pear, orange],
    pmap(fun(X) -> 
         try make_juice(X) of
             Result -> Result
         catch
             _:_ ->
             fail
         end
     end, Elements).
```

and the test:

```
rorra-air:~/erlang > erl
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V6.4  (abort with ^G)
1> c(juice).
juice.erl:11: Warning: this expression will fail with a 'badarith' exception
{ok,juice}
2> juice:test().
[apple_juice,fail,pear_juice,orange_juice]
3>
```